# matplolib ticks latex bold with python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, latex, bold, xticks

I am struggling with matplotlib and latex font.
I would like to have all in bold and in latex style. I have, consequently done as follows:

```
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.rc('font', family='serif',size=32)
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rc('legend', fontsize=32) 
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r"\usepackage{bm} \usepackage{amsmath}"


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(22,18))
```

This is however the result:

[image]

I have tried some options, but all seem referring to old matplolib version. I had a look to the official matpltlib page [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) but I can not understand how to set the bold option.
What do you think about?

Comment: i'm having the exactly problem. None of the solutions on internet have resolved it for me.